# Adding a fixed value to a DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have generated a DF from the below code:

```
url='https://www.rootsandrain.com/event4493/2017-aug-26-uci-world-cup-dh-7-val-di-sole/results/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', {'class':'list'})
headers = [heading.text for heading in table.find_all('th')]

response = requests.get(url)
dfs = pd.read_html(response.text)[0]

#rename headers
dfs.rename(columns = {'Pos⇧' : 'Race_Pos'}, inplace = True)

df_sf = dfs.iloc[:,[1,3,5,14]].copy()

#df_sf['Race_rank'] = df_sf['Race_Pos'].rank()
#df_sf['Race_Pos'] = df_sf['Race_Pos'].astype('str')
#df_sf['Race_Pos_Num'] = df_sf['Race_Pos'].str[:-2]

df_sf['Race_Pos']=df_sf.index

print(df_sf)

print(df_sf.dtypes)
```

Then also extracted the title (as yet uncleaned) using this code:

```
print(soup.h1)
```

However I want to add this value to each row of the table.  I can add a fixed value such as assign a new column with a value of 'X' but when I try to assign the title to the X value I get an error.

How to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to add a numeric value to all rows of a column in your dataframe?

Comment: It is unclear what your expected output looks like, please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you like to attach the race series and your near to your goal:

```
df_sf['Series'] = soup.h1.text
```

This will create a new column and applies the value of `soup.h1.text` to each of its rows.

###### Example

```
url='https://www.rootsandrain.com/event4493/2017-aug-26-uci-world-cup-dh-7-val-di-sole/results/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

dfs = pd.read_html(response.text)[0]

dfs.rename(columns = {'Pos⇧' : 'Race_Pos'}, inplace = True)
df_sf = dfs.iloc[:,[1,3,5,14]].copy()
df_sf['Race_Pos'] = df_sf.index

df_sf['Series'] = soup.h1.text

df_sf
```

###### Output

|  | Race_Pos | Name | Licence | Qualifier | Series |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Aaron GWIN | 10006516663 | 3:37.8281 | 2017 UCI World Cup DH round 7 at Val di Sole |
| 1 | 1 | Amaury PIERRON | 10008827283 | 3:41.7866 | 2017 UCI World Cup DH round 7 at Val di Sole |
| 2 | 2 | Loïc BRUNI | 10007544358 | 3:38.8623 | 2017 UCI World Cup DH round 7 at Val di Sole |
| 3 | 3 | Loris VERGIER | 10008723112 | 3:40.2095 | 2017 UCI World Cup DH round 7 at Val di Sole |
| 4 | 4 | Troy BROSNAN | 10007307417 | 3:39.8674 | 2017 UCI World Cup DH round 7 at Val di Sole |
| 5 | 5 | Laurie GREENLAND | 10009404738 | 3:48.38614 | 2017 UCI World Cup DH round 7 at Val di Sole |

...

Comment: Great, how to use those links into the orignal code (basically replace an iterate the url link that scraped to form the huge data set)?